# Is there a command to go a specific workspace?

Tags: command-line, workspaces, quicklists

I'm trying to make a quicklist on the Workspace Switcher launcher that allows for quick switching to a certain workspace. (My friend sometimes uses my computer and just doesn't enjoy keyboard shortcuts, so I want to help him out.)

So is there a command one could type in a terminal that would force a certain workspace to be focused on?

Comment: Also there is a possibility to set keyboard shortcut on systemsettings5 for kwin (switch desktop or else) or other desktop settings manager. then use xdotool to simulate the shortcut keys like xdotool key ctrl+alt+b;

Answer (score 46, accepted):

You can use [wmctrl](http://apt.ubuntu.com/p/wmctrl).

Basics commands:
`wmctrl -d` to show all of your workspaces.
`wmctrl -s <workspace_name>` to change to a specific workspace.

If you are using Compiz, you will have to do a trick because Compiz "workspaces" are actually Viewports of a single Workspace.

#### Trick Instructions

Check the output of `wmctrl -d` For example, mine is:

```
0  * DG: 4098x2304  VP: 1366,0  WA: 0,23 1366x745  N/A
```

This means that actually I have one Workspace of 4098 x 2304 instead of what I "think" I have (nine "workspaces", 3 x 3).
I was at what was supposed to be "workspace" 2, but actually I was at viewport (VP) 1366,0 (4098 / 3 = 1366) as showed by the output above.

So this is how it works: we take the whole Workspace and divide for the numbers of "workspaces" we "think" we have. In my case: 4098 / 3 = 1366 and 2304 / 3 = 768.

If I want to go to my "workspace" 1, the command is:

```
wmctrl -o 0,0
```

Then, if I want to go to my "workspace" 4, the command is:

```
wmctrl -o 0,768
```

If I want to go to my "workspace" 8, the command is:

```
wmctrl -o 1366,1536
```

If I want to go to my "workspace" 9, the command is:

```
wmctrl -o 2732,1536
```

Got it? ;-)

The `-o` flag "truncates" their values.
In other words it changes the "workspace" where the actual pixel is belonging to.
The following are equivalent:

```
wmctrl -o 0,0
wmctrl -o 1365,767
```

Comment: Is there a way to get to "the current desktop + 1"?

Comment: @xjcl You can do `expr $(xdotool get_desktop) + 1`

Comment: @Elijas One might as well use a pure xdotool solution in that case. Plus what happens on the last desktop?

Answer (score 17):

It is beautifully simple to achieve what you want with `xdotool`, which has multiple options for managing different workspaces (also known as 'desktops' within the program documentation). I find it can be very interesting and creative to string together commands from `man xdotool`; the commands I have formulated below might be useful in scripts.

**Note:** With some window managers, or if you are using `compiz`, you may need to use `xdotool` commands such as `set_desktop_viewport` and `get_desktop_viewport`. You may have to specify the commands in a different way like [desgua](https://askubuntu.com/users/12943/desgua) suggests above, but for me the `set_desktop` and `set_desktop_for_window` commands proved most useful on a non-compiz system.)

(**The solution is most useful for Xubuntu/Lubuntu users, or those who are not running compiz,etc.**)

To list the number of current workspaces, enter

```
xdotool get_num_desktops
```

The following commands will only work if you have at least 1 other workspace.

To change focus to your workspace 1, just enter

```
xdotool set_desktop 1
```

Then to return to the default workspace, enter

```
xdotool set_desktop 0
```

The workspace just needs to be specified as the last value in the command (1 or 2 or 3, etc).

To find the number of the workspace you are currently on, you could use

```
xdotool get_desktop
```

These commands could be used in scripts and they should be very useful for achieving what you what.

For how to switch applications to a particular desktop, see my answer here:

- [how to shift applications from workspace 1 to 2 using command](https://askubuntu.com/questions/31240/how-to-shift-applications-from-workspace-1-to-2-using-command)

For more useful options available for workspace switching, consult `man xdotool`.

Comment: I like this answer better than the accepted one, thank you. I used this to set two hot corners to easily switch between two workspaces.

Comment: Also useful: Switch to the next desktop to the left/right by using the relative flag: ```xdotool set_desktop --relative -- -1```

Answer (score 1):

I have implemented a script that does what you want.
Here it is: https://github.com/norswap/wmov/blob/master/wmov.sh

It works indeed as described in desgua's post. It also the capabilities to send windows to other workspaces.

Comment: Note: Doesn't work for virtual-desktop counts > 9.

Answer (score 0):

There is a script called [compiz-send.py](http://wiki.compiz.org/Plugins/Dbus?action=AttachFile&do=view&target=compiz-send.py) on the [compiz wiki](http://wiki.compiz.org/Plugins/Dbus) that partly adresses your question: it is not a specific workspace but you can get to the one next to it.

With this you can issue a command
`./compiz-dbus-send.py put put_viewport_left_key` 
`./compiz-dbus-send.py put put_viewport_right_key` 
and have the viewport go 1 to the left or to right.

Answer (score 0):

Going to a specific workspace and performing actions there can be implemented with Python and the library **pyautogui**, that enables Python scripts to perform mouse clicks, keystrokes, etc.

I wrote [a short tutorial](https://forum.peppermintos.com/index.php/topic,8801.0.html) in the forum for Peppermint OS about starting an app on a specific workplace.

Answer (score 0):

Update for desgua's answer - seems `wmctrl -d` outputs differently for Ubuntu 18.04.

This provides shortcuts for first, last and new workspaces too, or as a function you can call `__ws_switch N` where `N` is the workspace number.

```
0  * DG: 1920x1080  VP: 0,0  WA: 0,28 1920x1052  Workspace 1
1  - DG: 1920x1080  VP: N/A  WA: 0,28 1920x1052  Workspace 2
2  - DG: 1920x1080  VP: N/A  WA: 0,28 1920x1052  Workspace 3
3  - DG: 1920x1080  VP: N/A  WA: 0,28 1920x1052  Workspace 4
4  - DG: 1920x1080  VP: N/A  WA: 0,28 1920x1052  Workspace 5
5  - DG: 1920x1080  VP: N/A  WA: 0,28 1920x1052  Workspace 6
6  - DG: 1920x1080  VP: N/A  WA: 0,28 1920x1052  Workspace 7
7  - DG: 1920x1080  VP: N/A  WA: 0,28 1920x1052
```

Note the final blank workspace that isn't currently used. Assuming by the last workspace we mean the last workspace that is in use, the following could work:

```
cat << EOF >> "$script_dir"/ws.sh
#!/bin/sh

__ws_count() {
  __ws_counter="$(wmctrl -d | wc -l)"
  echo "$(( __ws_counter - 1 ))"
}

__ws_switch() {
  # Sanity test if "$1" is an int
  case "$1" in ''|*[^0-9]*) 
    echo "Input '$1' is not an integer"
    return 1 ;; 
  esac

  if test "$1" -gt "$(__ws_count)"; then
    echo "Workspace #$1 doesn't exist"
    return 1
  fi

  wmctrl -s "$1"
}

__ws_first() {
  __ws_switch 0
}

__ws_last() {
  __ws_counter="$(__ws_count)"
  __ws_switch "$(( __ws_counter - 1 ))"
}

__ws_new() {
  __ws_counter="$(__ws_count)"
  __ws_switch "$(( __ws_counter ))"
}
EOF
```

To add as a shortcut using `xbindkeys`, create the following shortcut files:

```
cat << EOF >> "$script_dir"/ws_first.sh
#!/bin/sh

. ./ws.sh

__ws_first
EOF
```

```
cat << EOF >> "$script_dir"/ws_last.sh
#!/bin/sh

. ./ws.sh

__ws_last
EOF
```

```
cat << EOF >> "$script_dir"/ws_new.sh
#!/bin/sh

. ./ws.sh

__ws_new
EOF
```

Then `chmod +x ./ws.sh ./ws_first.sh ./ws_last.sh ./ws_new.sh` to make them executable. Finally, to add to `.xbindkeysrc`:

```
cat << EOF >> ~/.xbindkeysrc
"$script_dir/ws_first.sh"
  Alt + Alt_L + w + f

"$script_dir/ws_last.sh"
  Alt + Alt_L + w + l

"$script_dir/ws_new.sh"
  Alt + Alt_L + w + n
EOF
```

**EDIT**: Don't forget to restart `xbindkeys` for changes to take effect:

```
killall xbindkeys && xbindkeys
```

Comment: Note that the shortcuts in the above are `alt + w + X` where `X` is `n` for a new workspace, `f` for the first, `l` for the last