# How to set default viewport on Compiz Desktop Wall?

Tags: compiz

I have 9 viewports, 3x3 in Compiz Desktop Wall. Every time I boot up it starts with viewport 1, in the left top corner. I'd like it to start with viewport 5, in the center. How can I set that?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One solution I thought about was to run a command 1-2 seconds after startup in order to change your current workspace to the wanted one.

This answer here explains it perfectly:

[Is there a command to go a specific workspace?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/41093/is-there-a-command-to-go-a-specific-workspace)

This answer explains how to run a command on startup

[How do I start applications automatically on login?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/48321/how-do-i-start-applications-automatically-on-login)

In the "Command" field, you will need to input

```
bash -c 'sleep 3; wmctrl -o X,Y'
```

where X,Y the coordinates that you have to take from the 1st answer I posted.

Comment: Thank you! I refined this idea to: `bash -c "while [ '\`wmctrl -d | grep 3840,1080\`' = '' ]; do wmctrl -o 3840,1080; sleep 1; done"` for my (X,Y) = (3840,1080).

Comment: Glad it worked.