# Start Ubuntu Focused on a Particular Workspace

Tags: startup, workspaces

Is there a way to have Ubuntu boot up focused on a particular workspace, e.g., workspace_2?

Note, this is not [how to always open an application on a particular workspace](https://askubuntu.com/questions/89946/open-application-in-specific-workspace), but to have, e.g., the second workspace the first one focused on when starting up Ubuntu.

Thank you for any help!

Comment: Just curious, why are you trying to do this?

Comment: Just how I use workspaces.  I have 5 in a row, and work in the center one.  Things I want to refer to but don't want cluttering my alt-tab list (like reference table), I'll put to one side.  Things I want open but don't use much (like Clash of Clans opened in a VM), I put all the way to one side.  So, I'd like to default open to the middle workspace.

Comment: Ok, do know how `cron` works?

Comment: Yeah, fairly well.  I can use that to focus on a given workspace at a given time, e.g., when I also schedule a reboot?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's actually simpler than I had imagined, you'll just need to add a command to your **Startup Applications** to find out which command that is, see [this question.](https://askubuntu.com/questions/41093/is-there-a-command-to-go-a-specific-workspace)

If you choose to go with the accepted answer, you'll need to install the package [`wmctrl`](http://apt.ubuntu.com/p/wmctrl). If the first solution doesn't work for you, you can use [`xdotool`](http://apt.ubuntu.com/p/xdotool)

For example, you might add the command "wmctrl -s 3" to go to your third workspace using `wmctrl`. But of course you should experiment with the command to see which method works for you, then add that command to the startup apps.

Comment: Fantastic!  That works perfectly.

Comment: In case it helps others, I use compiz, so I had to use the "trick" noted in [that question](http://askubuntu.com/questions/41093/is-there-a-command-to-go-a-specific-workspace), using `wmctrl -o 3840,0` as the command I added to **startup app** for my particular arrangement (3rd "Viewport" on a 9600 x 1000 "workspace").  Thanks so much, robobobklein!