# Keyboard shortcut for switch to workspace 11 doesn't work

Tags: keyboard, shortcut-keys, workspaces

I'm using Ubuntu 14.04 and I'm trying to setup a few keyboard shortcuts for switching to specific workspaces, but the one for switching to *#11* doesn't work.

The problem seems to be exclusive to workspace #11. For example I can set the shortcut for *Switch to workspace 9* to <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>1</kbd> and it works fine, but when I set *Switch to workspace 11* to <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>1</kbd>, Ubuntu acts as if there wasn't  a shortcut at all (eg. it activates Firefox's <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>1</kbd> shortcut of switching to the first tab)

Is there something I can do to correct this behavior, or is this a bug in Ubuntu?

Answer (score 0):

I have no idea why this doesn't work, but I ran into the same problem myself and I have a workaround.

First, you need to find a command which lets you switch to workspace 11 (and in my case, also workspace 12)

Take a look at [this answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/41125/370026) to know how to do that.

For instance, on my system the command to switch to workspace 11 was `wmctrl -o 3840,2160`. This is resolution dependent, so I'd suggest looking at the original answer to find the command that reliably works for you.

Once you have the command, go to

```
System Settings > Keyboard > Shortcuts > Custom Shortcuts
```

And add these commands as custom shortcuts. Now assign any key to them and it should work.