# Command run in terminal, not with shortcuts

Tags: command-line, shortcut-keys, workspaces, mate

As explain in this [thread](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1015401/mate-switch-workspace-commande), I want to add shortcuts to switch workspaces (in Mate).

I found a way to switch workspace for the terminal: `wmctrl -s $(wmctrl -d | grep "*" | awk '{print $1+1}')`.

But this command line does not work when I add it in the shortcut manager. Does any one know why ?

Comment: Does it work if you specifically run it with bash, i.e. set this as shortcut `bash -c "wmctrl -s $(wmctrl -d | grep '*' | awk '{print $1+1}')"`?

Comment: Yes it works ! You can add it as an answer :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

IIRC keyboard shortcut commands are running in an `sh` shell, which doesn't have all the features Bash has.

Your command uses some bash-specific syntax though, which is why it doesn't work. The simplest fix is to simply run it in a Bash shell by replacing it with this command below:

```
bash -c "wmctrl -s $(wmctrl -d | grep '*' | awk '{print $1+1}')"
```