# Make wmctrl ignore other-than-current workspace's windows

Tags: unity, shortcut-keys, workspaces

I rely on wmctrl a lot to switch between windows, basically to avoid typing alt-tab many times. I've always used one workspace but now I want to begin using more than one.

I was wondering if it is possible to modify the context of wmctrl so that when I type `wmctrl -l`, only windows from the current workspace are shown, instead of all windows from all workspaces.

For example, assuming I have a Firefox window opened in workspace 1. I have a keyboard shortcut on `ctrl+alt+f` that executes `wmctrl -a firefox`, which switches to Firefox. If I open a new Firefox window on workspace 2 and type `ctrl+alt+f`, it will switch to the window at workspace 1, which is not what I want.

Any suggestions/ideas on how to solve this?

**EDIT**: I'm using compiz (Unity)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you're using Compiz (run `wmctrl -m` if not sure), wmctrl only sees 1 desktop (2nd field of wmctrl -l, ie 0) but you can use the geometry (-G) option to know what window is on what virtual desktop. All windows in your current desktop will have an x-position between 0 and your screen's width. Same for the y-position between 0 and your screen's height.
So you can use something like that

```
#!/bin/bash

SCREEN_W=$(xwininfo -root | sed -n 's/^  Width: \(.*\)$/\1/p')
SCREEN_H=$(xwininfo -root | sed -n 's/^  Height: \(.*\)$/\1/p')

NAME='Navigator.Firefox'

wmctrl -xlG | awk -v W="$SCREEN_W" -v H="$SCREEN_H" -v NAME="$NAME" '$7==NAME && $3>=0 && $3<W && $4>=0 && $4<H {print $1}' | while read WINS; do wmctrl -ia "$WINS"; done

exit 0
```

You can hardcode your screen's width and height if you will, and NAME if you want a one-liner.
Im not sure how you want to handle multiple windows matching NAME. That will focus them all.

For metacity, desktop number of windows can be found using `wmctrl -l` and grepping the 2nd field.

Comment: The only issue is that, besides my laptop's screen (14"), I use a monitor at the lab and another at home, the three of them having distinct resolutions, so the x-position varies depending on which display I'm using. I guess I could define ranges, mmm. Will try it. I wonder if there are alternatives to make wmctlr know the desktop number on compiz

Comment: That's what the 2 first lines are for. They get your screen resolution (SCREEN_W: width and SCREEN_H: height) and pass them in awk.. You can either use the code abore for all 3 or use 3 different commands for each of them, ae (1440x900): `wmctrl -xlG | awk '$7=="Navigator.Firefox" && $3>=0 && $3<1440 && $4>=0 && $4<900 {print $1}' | while read WIN; do wmctrl -ia "$WIN"; done`

Comment: i see, cool! that solves my issue then. Thanks! Will work on it and comment back on how it went

Comment: @ivotron how did it go?

Comment: @user55822 How could one move an application from one workspace to another with `wmctrl` (and `compiz`)? Could you give an example one-liner and/or script, please please please?

Comment: @nuttyaboutnatty Yes, [this](https://github.com/ivotron/dotfiles/blob/master/.scripts/bringtocurrent) it's what works for me. You invoke it by doing something like `~/.scripts/bringtocurrent Firefox`. That'll bring Firefox to the current window.

Comment: @ivotron Hmm. That's a start. But [what I'm looking for](http://askubuntu.com/questions/251344/how-to-prevent-applications-from-separate-workspaces-all-landing-on-a-single-wor) is to have a script / one-liner that would put, say, Firefox on Workspace 1, Geany on Workspace 2, Okular on Workspace 3 and Nautilus on Workspace 4, -- independently of the current Workspace and all "at once" (I don't want to run four separate commands, else I'm quicker using keyboard shortcuts). Could you easily "upgrade" your script? Please... :-) ?

Comment: ps: a bounty expired on [that question](http://askubuntu.com/questions/251344/how-to-prevent-applications-from-separate-workspaces-all-landing-on-a-single-wor) last week, but I am more than willing to award one again for a good solution!

Comment: sorry @nuttyaboutnatty, while I'd love to work on it, I don't have time :-(

Comment: @ivotron there's no rush. maybe you could put it on the back-burner for now... ;)

Answer (score 0):

I have the answer for 2022, it's quite powerful one based on The newest wmctrl logic, welp it mimics autohotkey on windows

So first we need to get the active desktop / workspace

```
wmctrl -d | grep "*" | awk --field-separator="  "  '{print $1}'
```

After that, you can piece it to get the list ONLY Window on That desktop

```bash
D=$(wmctrl -d | grep "*" | awk --field-separator="  "  '{print $1}')
WINNAME="GVIM"
# Or you can get the full name as hex, more accurate for same window name
WIN=$(wmctrl -l | grep "  $DESKTOP " | grep -i $WIN | awk '{print $1}')
# WIN will be filled with 0xYYYY ID in hex or use simple winname
IN=$(wmctrl -l | grep "  $DESKTOP " | grep -i gvim | awk --field-separator="$(hostname) " '{print $2}')
# Get the number of window contain it's name
STATUS=$(wmctrl -l | grep "  $DESKTOP " | grep -i $WINNAME | wc -l)
```

Then you can check it using if like this (For winname)

```bash
if [ $STATUS -gt 0 ]
then
   activeWindow=$(xprop -id $(xprop -root _NET_ACTIVE_WINDOW | cut -d ' ' -f 5) WM_NAME | cut -d '"' -f 2)      
   # zenity --notification --text="$activeWindow"
   if [[ $activeWindow =~ "$WINNAME" ]]
   then
       wmctrl -r "$WIN" -b toggle,hidden
   else
       wmctrl -a "$WIN"
   fi
else
   /usr/bin/gvim # if the app hasn't started yet, start it
fi
```

OR

For Hex ID

```bash
# ... output omitted
   if [[ $activeWindow =~ "$WINNAME" ]]
   then
       wmctrl -i -r "$WIN" -b toggle,hidden
   else
       wmctrl -i -a "$WIN"
   fi
# ... output omitted, see source before
```

So if you piece it all together (for using window name, this is not bullet prof as if has same name between workspace, well, it will follow the other workspace)

```bash
#!/bin/bash

DESKTOP=$(wmctrl -d | grep "*" | awk --field-separator="  "  '{print $1}')
STATUS=$(wmctrl -l | grep "  $DESKTOP " | grep -i gvim | wc -l)
WIN=$(wmctrl -l | grep "  $DESKTOP " | grep -i gvim | awk --field-separator="$(hostname) " '{print $4}')
# zenity --notification --text="$STATUS $DESKTOP $WIN"

if [ $STATUS -gt 0 ]
then
   activeWindow=$(xprop -id $(xprop -root _NET_ACTIVE_WINDOW | cut -d ' ' -f 5) WM_NAME | cut -d '"' -f 2)      
   # zenity --notification --text="$activeWindow"
   if [[ $activeWindow =~ "GVIM" ]]
   then
       wmctrl -r $WIN -b toggle,hidden
   else
       wmctrl -a $WIN
   fi
else
   /usr/bin/gvim
fi
```

OR BULLET PROF using HEX ID

```bash
#!/bin/bash

DESKTOP=$(wmctrl -d | grep "*" | awk --field-separator="  "  '{print $1}')
STATUS=$(wmctrl -l | grep "  $DESKTOP " | grep -i gvim | wc -l)
WIN=$(wmctrl -l | grep "  $DESKTOP " | grep -i gvim | awk '{print $1}')
#zenity --notification --text="$WIN"
if [ $STATUS -gt 0 ]
then
   activeWindow=$(xprop -id $(xprop -root _NET_ACTIVE_WINDOW | cut -d ' ' -f 5) WM_NAME | cut -d '"' -f 2)      
   #zenity --notification --text="$STATUS $DESKTOP \"$WIN\" $activeWindow"
   if [[ $activeWindow =~ "GVIM" ]]
   then
       wmctrl -i -r "$WIN" -b toggle,hidden
   else
       wmctrl -i -a "$WIN"
   fi
else
   /usr/bin/gvim
fi
```

-i in `man wmctrl` means :

-i     Interpret window arguments () as a numeric value rather than a string name for the window. **If the numeric value
starts with the prefix '0x' it is assumed to be a hexadecimal number**

You can get window toggle like AHK Script on Windows, but more powerful than it should.

This script tested on XFCE, and works, either Xubuntu 22.04 or Fedora 36.