# Why don't I get Unity as an option when logging in?

Tags: 14.04, unity, xubuntu, desktop-environments, multiple-desktops

I'm on Xubuntu 14.04.

I ran `sudo apt-get install unity`. It ran successfully.

But when I log out, I don't get the option to log in again with Unity. This is what I see:

[image]

I have tried rebooting. Did I miss something?

Comment: What do commands `stat /usr/share/xsessions/ubuntu.desktop ` and  `which unity` tell you ?

Comment: @Serg They give `stat: cannot stat ‘/usr/share/xsessions/ubuntu.desktop’: No such file or directory` and `/usr/bin/unity` respectively.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The sessions typically are listed on the login screen if they are read from `.desktop` files provided in `/usr/share/xsessions` folder.
On my system ( default Unity desktop ) I have the following `ubuntu.desktop` file :

```
[Desktop Entry]
Name=Ubuntu
Comment=This session logs you into Ubuntu
Exec=gnome-session --session=ubuntu
TryExec=unity
Icon=
Type=Application
X-LightDM-DesktopName=Unity
X-Ubuntu-Gettext-Domain=gnome-session-3.0
```

I suggest you add the following file , but remove the `Icon=` part and perhaps `X-LightDM-DesktopName=Unity`

Comment: Just to clarify,  you're saying i should create a file called `ubuntu.desktop` in my `/usr/share/xsessions` folder and paste that text into it? (except for the lines you mentioned?)

Comment: @Fiksdal yes, that's exactly what i am saying

Comment: I did that. It did give me "Ubuntu" as one of the options. I selected it and logged in, but now I'm getting only the wallpaper and a mouse cursor. I think I'll try a reboot.

Comment: @Fiksdal um , install `compizconfig-settings-manager`  and find the `Unity` plugin. click on that, and there will be an option to the left to enable it. Do that.  In reality , Unity is just a plugin for `compiz`.  From time to time it just crashes for whatever reason and you have to reenable that plugin. No more no less - Unity is just a plugin

Comment: If I start with a clean install, in what order should I do things? Like 1. Install Unity, 2. Create the .desktop file, 3. Install compizconig?

Comment: How about installing ubuntu-desktop instead of just Unity?

Comment: Hi, I solved the problem. I formated and reinstalled Xubuntu, then installed `ubuntu-desktop` instead, and it worked. The thing is, though, I still had to wait for a while in the state where there was just the wallpaper and cursor. This doesn't really surprise me, as the resources of the system are extremely limited. So what I'm thinking is, maybe with the method that you gave the same thing would have happened, if I would have just waited through it instead of doing a restart, it would have worked. So I'm accepting and upvoting this answer. Is that alright? I'm not sure it would have worked.

Comment: @Fiksdal   `ubuntu-desktop` basically gives you the same environment as the default Ubuntu , so I see nothing wrong with that if you're not against the boot theme being changed.  I'm sure we could have figured it out eventually ,but as long as everything works and everybody is happy  - that's all that matters. Enjoy Unity ! :)  Let me know if you'd be interested in some of the scripts i wrote for it

Comment: Scripts you wrote for what?

Comment: For Unity of course ^_^ For example [this one](http://askubuntu.com/a/758339/295286) moves all windows form one workspace to another , and [this one](http://askubuntu.com/a/769978/295286) blocks notifications , like Mac OS X "Do not disturb" mode. Ive more of those , for different purposes ,too,.

Comment: Wow, those are nice. Did you make a list of all the scripts you have written?

Comment: @Fiksdal well , I have over a thousand answers already on AskUbuntu, but some of the big and useful scripts , I put on my https://github.com/SergKolo/sergrep

Answer (score 0):

Try:

sudo apt-get --purge remove unity

Then reinstall unity BUT THIS TIME WHILE INSTALLING IF A SCREEN POPS UP ASKING YOU TO CHOOSE BETWEEN "LIGHTDM" AND SOMETHING ELSE, CHOOSE "LIGHTDM".

Comment: But no such screen popped up when I installed Unity the first time, so why would it pop up if I purge and reinstall?

Comment: This same action can be achieved by doing `sudo dpkg-reconfigure lightdm`

Comment: @Serg Is `dpkg-reconfigure` worth trying?

Comment: @Fiksdal no , because what Xubuntu is using  , I believe is a variation of `lightdm`  , so you won't have other choices there. If you install `gnome`, then sure, you will have another option. This however is also pointless because it changes which login screen you see by default, it doesn't affect the session options , AFAIK.

Comment: I had installed unity on ubuntu gnome and it worked fine

Answer (score 0):

Try

> sudo apt-get --purge remove unity

and

> sudo apt-get install ubuntu-desktop