# Starting a windowed program in a specific workspace, from command line

Tags: unity, workspaces, window-management

I wonder if I can "send" a windowed program into a specific workspace when I start it via command line.

For example, I would like to start my computer with a certain number of windowed programs open in different workspaces. Is this possible? What are some basic concepts behind this?

I am using Unity, on Ubuntu 14.04.

I also tried to start `gdevilspie` but it seems to be [affected by a bug.](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/gdevilspie/+bug/1161594)

thanks! :)

Answer (score 3):

Using `wmctrl`, example `gedit`:

```
gedit & sleep 3; wmctrl -i -r `wmctrl -l -p | grep $! | awk '{ print $1 }'` -t 1
```

- `gedit &` run gedit in backgroud
- `sleep 3` sleep for 3sec wait for window creation (my machine little bit slow)
- `$!` return PID of previous command (ie: gedit pid)
- `wmctrl -l -p | grep PID | awk '{ print $1 }'` get WID from gedit PID
- `wmctrl -i -r WID -t 1` move window with WID to 2nd desktop

Another way:

```
wmctrl -s 1 ; gedit & sleep 3; wmctrl -s 0;
```

- Switch to 2nd desktop, launch gedit, wait 3sec; switch back to 1st desktop

Reference:

- [how to shift applications from workspace 1 to 2 using command](https://askubuntu.com/questions/31240/how-to-shift-applications-from-workspace-1-to-2-using-command)
- [`man wmctrl`](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/trusty/man1/wmctrl.1.html)

Comment: If you're using compiz the above don't work because you have one workspace with multiple viewports -- see https://askubuntu.com/a/41125/264966

Answer (score 0):

It's basically the same @user.dz answered, just parametrized and instead of sleeping for 3 seconds for the windows handler to be created this one loops until find it.

```
# workspace target
_WS=3
export DISPLAY=:0 

gedit &
_PID="$!" 
_WID=""
while [[ $_WID == "" ]]; do
  _WID=$(wmctrl -l -p 2>/dev/null | grep $_PID | awk '{ print $1 }')
sleep 1
done

wmctrl -i -r $_WID -t $_WS
```