# How to make applications launch in desired workspace

Tags: workspaces

I'm working in one workspace. I switch to a different workspace and launch Firefox (by clicking its button in the sidebar). I switch back to the original workspace while Firefox is launching.

I wanted Firefox to run in the alternate workspace. But it opens its window in the original one.

Seems like there should be a way for apps to notice which workspace they're being launched into, and honor that choice.

Comment: Actually, no. I don't want to hard-code the workspace for each application. I'd like to do it in an ad hoc fashion: Switch workspace. Launch an app. Go back to what I was doing while the app launches in the other workspace.

Comment: Perhaps this helps [how to shift applications from workspace 1 to 2 using command](http://askubuntu.com/questions/31240/how-to-shift-applications-from-workspace-1-to-2-using-command)

Comment: @EliahKagan I am curious why you think this is a duplicate (I saw you voted to close in review). It doesn't look like one to me, and OP doesn't think so either.