# Certain windows are not opening in the last position/size I used them at

Tags: 11.04, window, resize

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to save window positions?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/8834/how-to-save-window-positions)

Certain windows are not opening in the last position/size I used them at. Opening "compose a message" with evolution through the message menu on the toolbar opens a window that is always in the top left of my screen. Opening Firefox 4.0 always opens maximized, even if i last used it in "windowed" mode. Other things I've tried that won't remember my custom positions: ccsm, terminal, gedit, sound recorder, calculator. Some other stuff works fine like banshee, empathy, shutter, deluge.

Is this a bug? Is there a way to make these applications open in their last used positions/sizes?

Comment: it happen also to me and we're not the ones, try to report the bug

Comment: yes it's a bug dating back to at least 2007 https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/metacity/+bug/124315

Answer (score 1):

Further to what David said, you can use CCSM to play with this behavior.

In the 'Place Windows' plug-in option you can pick from a range of options. I've found 'smart' preserves the majority of my settings.

This is especially true if you've got a dual monitor setup; i found i needed to use 'place across all outputs' to get my expected behavior.

I think Unity defaults to attempting to maximize applications, however. At least, that's what I've found.

Answer (score 0):

Could you check the plugin "set windows"? (sorry, i have it in spanish) in CCSM? <strike>(the one i show you in the screenshot)</strike>.

Maybe disabling the plugin or just tweaking its settings the way you want could help.