# where is the power button setting on 12.04?

Tags: 12.04, shutdown, button

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Hibernate missing from power menu and when I press laptop power button](https://askubuntu.com/questions/111669/hibernate-missing-from-power-menu-and-when-i-press-laptop-power-button)

I upgraded my system to 12.04 and i'm quite pleased so far.

When i hit the power button on my laptop the system hybernates. There was once a menu where I could change this setting (e.g. to lock screen or ask if shutdown). Where is it now?

Comment: the question marked as "duplicate" answers only the first part (regarding hibernation) the question about the power button remains unclear.