# How to remember currently running applications in 12.04?

Tags: startup-applications

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to save window positions?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/8834/how-to-save-window-positions)

I cannot find the option "Remember currently running applications" in 12.04 whereas in 10.04, it was along with startup applications.

Any idea where I can find it?

UPDATE : As you can see from the comments, this feature has been removed. So as an answer, I'd like to know if there is a workaround to this. So the question remains the same, but instead of searching for the in-built option, I now seek a workaround.