# Remembering window positions in Ubuntu 12.04

Tags: unity

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to save window positions?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/8834/how-to-save-window-positions)

Is it possible to install something which makes Ubuntu 12.04 remember the positions of windows and restore those positions if a window/application is closed and re-opened? I am aware that Ubuntu itself does not do this out of the box and will not do it.

I'm happy to install some third-party app which does this, or perhaps write something third-party using a tool (devilspie?), as long as it works with core Ubuntu 12.04 using the standard Unity desktop (that is: shifting to a different desktop or leaving Unity is not an acceptable option for this question). I'd be interested primarily in answers which also give some indication of whether they're likely to continue to work in later versions of Ubuntu, and whether they're working with or against the direction in which Unity is heading (for example, if a suggested solution uses a compiz extension, will that compiz extension continue to work with Unity, in your estimation?)

[This question was asked and answered for Ubuntu 10.04](https://askubuntu.com/questions/8834/how-to-save-window-positions) which *did* have such a remember-window-positions feature; Ubuntu 12.04 does not, so this is not a duplicate.