# How to make Nautilus remember the windows position?

Tags: nautilus

I can't see any tweak about this in dconf or compiz. Can someone explain is there any way to make Nautilus remember its position before the closing?

Ubuntu 12.04

Comment: Not the position where the window was closed, but the position where it will open is able to fix by using the **Place Windows** plugin in CCSM.

Comment: I dont use CCSM in 12.04 but when I did in 11.10 the "Place Windows" plug in led to undesirable results.can damage you system I think because  Unity's snapping windows needs to be disabled to accomodate it.  +1 for the question

Comment: It's not really possible with Ubuntu. see http://askubuntu.com/questions/8834/how-do-i-save-sessions-or-reopen-last-used-applications

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One solution to this problem is using the software gnome-tweak-tool. Here is how step by step: (WARNING! read at the bottom of this message first: there will be some bugs if you follow the steps but it is fully and easily reversible)

1) if you do not have installed gnome-tweak-tool you can find it in Ubuntu Software Center. In the search area type "advanced settings" and install the first matching result.
Close Ubuntu Software Center.

2) This app will appear in Unity with the name "Advanced Settings", if not, search it with dash with this name.

3) Launch this app and go to "Desktop" and change "Have file manager handle the desktop" from OFF to ON. That's it! Close the app and now Nautilus will remember the last size and position.

WARNING! There are some side effects to this action, but it is fully reversibile if you put "Have file manager handle the desktop" from ON to OFF. Some bugs that I have noticed after the modification: slow unity, slow firefox and others.

Comment: Thanks about this tip, but my laptop doesn't new and such freezes are inappropriate. But it may help for others. Actually I use the advice about the compiz plugin **Place Management** - I had changed the placement from 'smart' to 'in center'.

Answer (score 2):

My solution might not help with remembering the last position exactly, depending on where the shortcut is on your desktop (if you are opening a shortcut from the desktop, that is)...

In Compiz, choose Window Management and then Place Windows (making sure it is enabled first).

Under the General tab in Placement Mode, choose Pointer. This will ensure it opens the window wherever the shortcut resides on your desktop, so this is the best solution.

Answer (score 1):

I cannot give you a "perfect" answer to this issue but I've been trying to solve and I've made some progress that you may try as partial workaround.

```
sudo gconf-editor
```

Add a new "String" key inside `/apps/nautilus/preferences` called `navigation_window_saved_geometry` and specify a size and position e.g. `879x620+483+352`

Close the configuration editor and launch Nautilus. If it doesn't appear with the size and position you specified try to launch it from a terminal window it should work.

The problem is that if you change the position and size and close Nautilus it will not keep this properties. It will keep on open in whatever position and size you specified with the Configuration editor.

So, it doesn't fully work (at least not for me); it is just a partial workaround.