# Is hibernation supported with the Intellibook on 12.04?

Tags: 12.04, laptop, hibernate

I installed Ubuntu 12.04 on an Intellibook (Intel®  Atom™ N450 processor, Intel® NM10 Express Chipset, Intel®  GMA  3150), activated a swap partition and tried `pm-hibernate`.
It seems to work but when I switch back on, the system will boot without restoring the old state.

Is there a way to activate hibernation on Intellibook or is it not working on the given hardware?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If `sudo pm-hibernate` doesn't *completely* work (hibernate and resume), hibernation isn't compatible with your current hardware.

You can try the alternative TuxOnIce hibernation method which has somewhat better compatibility, but no guarantees.

Please see [section B of this answer](https://askubuntu.com/questions/8834/how-do-i-save-sessions-or-reopen-last-used-applications/143616#143616) for how to try TuxOnIce hibernation.