# How to reopen the folders that were open before shutdown?

Tags: 12.04, configuration, shutdown, directory

I know how to configure it on Windows but don't know if Ubuntu has this feature.

Is it possible?

Comment: Do you mean something like [this](http://askubuntu.com/a/174733/62483)?

Comment: I believe KDE does this by default too.

Comment: I didn't know that is called 'session'. No wonder that I could not found anything.