# Restore previous applications on restart in Ubuntu 13.04 easily?

Tags: gnome

How to restore previous applications when I restart the computer in Ubuntu 13.04? This post ([How do I save/remember last-used window position and size for applications?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/8834/how-do-i-save-sessions-or-reopen-last-used-applications)) is not in 13.04 and I actually tried to use what Lucio suggested in the post, (i.e. dconf -> org -> gnome -> gnome-session and click on checkbox), but it didn't work at all. Even if what izx suggested in the post works on 13.04 too, which I don't know it does, do I have to spend three hours just setting the functionality of restoring previous applications on? OS X offers it either on default, or force you to just three minutes work. Is it feasible to do such a minimal work and still get what I wanted? Sorry but I don't think it is worth three hours to just set restoring my applications on.

Thanks.

Comment: Did below solution ever work for you?  (as I have a duplicate for it, but as long as it's not an "accepted" answer I can't duplicate...)

Comment: Any feed-back, please?

Comment: @Fabby It had passed so, so much since I posted the question, and I had already ditched Ubuntu by the end of 2013 and gone back to OS X since then. So it's not feasible to validate your answer. Sorry...

Comment: Too bad...  Thanks for the feed-back.

Answer (score 1):

I use CompizConfig Settings Manager to set my applications on specific workspaces on specific coordinates.  E.g. psensor always in the top-right corner of workspace (WS) 2, liferea always in the top left corner WS2, boinc in the lower left corner of WS3, ...

All these applications also get added to "Startup Applications" so that when I log on, everything is in the right place and open...

Instead of logging off I also use TuxOnIce to hibernate my machine so that ALL applications currently running get back where they were.

IMHO, if you spend 3 hours every time to set up your environment, you'd better spend that time configuring things...

Good enough??? ;)

Comment: Don't thank me!  ;-) If you like my answer, just click the little grey **☑** under the "0" now turning it into beautiful green.  If you do not like my answer, click on the little grey down-arrow below the 0, and if you *really* like my answer, click on the little grey checkmark *and* the little up-arrow...  If you have any further questions, go to http://askubuntu.com/questions/ask

Answer (score -1):

If you are running Virtual Machines(either VMware or Hyper-V) you can just save the state of your VM.

Then when you restart it from your Hyper-V Server Manager, it will be at the same state it was before.

For instance:

- Go to the Hyper-V Server Manager in Windows
- select your running Ubuntu VM
- Right click with mouse
- Click Save
- VM state will be saved
- After it's saved when you restart it it will be @ the same place you
  left it....

Then Bob's your uncle! :)

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu! I recommend [edit]ing this answer to expand it with specific details about how to do this. (See also [How do I write a good answer?](/help/how-to-answer) for general advice about what sorts of answers are considered most valuable on Ask Ubuntu.)