# Remember Each Window/Browser size and location

Tags: 14.04, gnome, cinnamon

Ubuntu 14.04.1 LTS with latest Cinnamon updated.

Is there a way/software to remember the size and location of each window/application/browser that survives a reboot?
For example after logging in, I want to launch 2 terminals and a 3 browser windows on 2 monitors with specific size and locations.

Does something like this exist?
Any pointers would be appreciated.
Thank you.

Answer (score -1):

This seems like a duplicate of [How do I save/remember last-used window position and size for applications?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/8834/how-do-i-save-remember-last-used-window-position-and-size-for-applications), check that out and see if it is the same.

Comment: Except that this was cleanly asking about Cinnamon and the link is discussing gnome.